# CPU Fan running post shutdown

Tags: fan, usb-c

After I turn off my computer my CPU fan continues to spin albeit at a slower RPM until I unplug the USB-C cable connected to the back of my monitor. I have also disconnected the power cable to the CPU and it still spins. Happy to add more details if needed. Any idea how bad this is and or what can I do to fix? Thank you

Comment: Who is the manufacturer and what model is it?

Comment: It’s a thermal take fan which has worked fine for years until I installed this usb c card and connected it to the monitor.

Comment: Look for possible miswiring or a source of heat that does not cool down promptly.